# ElasticsSearch AWS Connect failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to connect ElasticSearch5 on my local with an AWS remote server however I am having issues connecting on port 80 (Getting None of the configured Nodes are available error) however I am able to access using cURL request.

I am using a transport client on my ElasticSearch for connecting, Is this the issue? Is there any way around this?

Following is the error message:

```
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:314)
```

Comment: Are you running a copy of elasticsearch on an EC2 instance, or are you using Amazon's elasticsearch service?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch has two default ports for outside communication, first 9200 for HTTP requests (seems like you mapped it to port 80 or used reverse proxy) and second 9300 for inter communication - betweem the cluster nodes.
Are you sure you opened the security group for inbound port 9300?

More details about the transport module: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html

Comment: Yes I mapped it to port 80 for connecting with AWS

Comment: And does port 9300 is open for inbound connections?